# Unable to implement picker view in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uipickerview

I tried implementing picker view and passed the data to picker view got crashed while clicking in textfield can anyone help me how to resolve this issue ?

here is my crash report after clicking on textfield

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view
>   controller: should
>   have parent view controller: but requested parent is:'

```
var countryArray = [Country]()
var shippingAddressEditData : CustomerShippingAddress?
```

in view did load

```
countryPickerView.delegate = self
countryPickerView.dataSource = self
countryTextField.inputView = countryPickerView
countryListDownloadJsonwithURL(countryAPI: countryURL)
```

Json function to get countries and states

```
func countryListDownloadJsonwithURL(countryAPI: String) {
        let url = NSURL(string: countryAPI)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String:Any]] {
                for item in jsonObj! {
                    let dict = Country(dict: item)
                    self.countryArray.append(dict)
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                  self.countryPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Here is my model class data

```
struct Country {

let country : String
let selected : Bool
let countryId : String
var state = [State]()

init(dict:[String:Any]) {
    self.country = (dict["country"] as? String)!
    self.selected = (dict["selected"] as? Bool)!
    self.countryId = (dict["country_id"] as? String)!
    if let customAttribute = dict["state"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        var result = [State]()
        for obj in customAttribute {
            result.append(State(dict: obj))
        }
        self.state = result
    } else {
        self.state = [State]()
    }
  }   
 }

struct State {

let state : String
let stateValue : Int

init(dict: [String:Any]) {
    self.state = (dict["state"] as? String)!
    self.stateValue = (dict["state_value"] as? Int)!
   }
}


public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    if pickerView == countryPickerView{
        return 1
    }else {
        return 1
    }
}

public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    if pickerView == countryPickerView {
        return countryArray.count
    }
    else {
        return countryArray[component].state.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == countryPickerView {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return countryArray[row].country
    }
    else {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return countryArray[component].state[row].state
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == countryPickerView {
        countryTextField.text = countryArray[row].country
        countryPickerView.isHidden = true
    }
    else {
        self.stateButton.setTitle(countryArray[component].state[row].state, for: .normal)
    }
}
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    countryPickerView.isHidden = false
    return false
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe share some code or information about how you setup the view controllers and UI elements? I can imagine the problem is not in the pickerView delegate methods, or the model data.

Comment: I had placed a picker view using storyboard may the problem lies with this or what ? @jbehrens94

Comment: I don't think the pickerView is the problem, but I think there could be a problem in the way the storyboard is setup. Could you maybe post a screenshot of the contents of your storyboard?

Comment: Also: did you actually connect the pickerView to the viewController? Otherwise the app will crash as well.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0bu8.png here is my layout in storyboard  @jbehrens94

Comment: yes I had connected picker view to view controller @jbehrens94